# Append data to Google Spreadsheet using API and Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, rest, google-api

I'm doing my first steps with Google API. Currently I have a need to add some data to existing spreadsheet. For some purposes I need to use `Invoke-RestMethod` instead of any already created modules.

For a test purpose I wanted to add single entry for now. I'm using this code:

```
$requestUri = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$($SpreadsheetID)/values/$("SheetName!A1:F195"):append   

$body = @{
   range = 'SheetName!A1:F195';
   values = @{
       'Field1' = 'Test';
       'Field2' = 'Test';
       'Field3' = 'Test'; 
       'Field4' = 'Test'; 
       'Field5' = 'Test';
       'Link' = 'https://test.com'
   };
};

$test = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $body

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"} -Uri $requestUri -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $test
```

As a response, I'm receiving this error 400 - Bad request.
Sheet already containing some data. Field names in my `$body` variable are exactly same like in spreadsheet. A196 is first empty cell in my spreadsheet. I was kind of expecting that it will just enter those values into that row basically.

I still didn't know what is wrong, so I decided to use Google API Playground. When I filled everything, request looks like this:

```
POST /v4/spreadsheets/<SpreadsheetID>/values/SheetName!A1:F195:append HTTP/1.1
Host: sheets.googleapis.com
Content-length: 385
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <code>
{
    'range':  'SheetName!A1:F195',
    'values':  {
                   'Field1':'Test',
                   'Field2':'Test',
                   'Field3':'Test',
                   'Field4':'Test',
                   'Field5':'Test',
                   'Link':'https://test.com'
               }
}
```

As a response I'm getting this:

```
"code": 400, 
    "details": [
      {
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "data.values", 
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Field1\" at 'data.values': Cannot find field."
          }, 
          {
            "field": "data.values", 
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Field1\" at 'data.values': Cannot find field."
          }, 
          {
            "field": "data.values", 
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Field1\" at 'data.values': Cannot find field."
          }, 
          {
            "field": "data.values", 
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Field1\" at 'data.values': Cannot find field."
          }, 
          {
            "field": "data.values", 
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Field1\" at 'data.values': Cannot find field."
          }, 
          {
            "field": "data.values", 
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Link\" at 'data.values': Cannot find field."
          }
        ], 
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest"
      }
    ]
```

But I really have not clue what is wrong here. I'm fighting with this some time already, but I'm out of ideas ATM. Appreciate if somebody could point me to correct route.

@EDIT
I find information that while appending, range should cover existing table. However chaning range to A1:F195 gives exactly same error.

Comment: You are sending an HTTP request which is HTML format.  HTML there are special characters that must be encoded like the exclamation mark.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: As it seems, this wasn't the problem. It was all about how $body was defined. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: Really the same issue.  If the body is defined as json, either the request is automatically encoding or GZIP is being used.  The root cause of the issue is the HTML special characters.

Comment: Possibly, I've tried with escape with "`", "\" and by doing "[char]0x0021". Unfortunately all have failed. Or maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: The escaping is shown in link in previous comment.  It can be done using : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string). Encode what you are putting in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I found some solution by trying different things. Maybe it's not best one, but definitelly one that actually works. The case was that actually `$body` in specific form. One that worked (at least not displaying same error) was this:

```
{
    'range':  'SheetName!A1:F195',
    'values':  [
                  [
                   'Test',
                   'Test',
                   'Test',
                   'Test',
                   'Test',
                   'https://test.com'
                  ]
            ]
}
```

So putting values in double square brackets and just values. Using this I was able to get another error in API Playground:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", 
    "message": "'valueInputOption' is required but not specified", 
    "code": 400
  }
}
```

So after adding `?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED` to `$requestUri` I was at last able to have row added.

Working code in Powershell looks like this:

```
$requestUri = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$($SpreadsheetID)/values/$("SheetName!A:F"):append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED"

$body = @"
{
    'range':  'SheetName!A:F',
    'values':  [
                  [
                   'Test',
                   'Test',
                   'Test',
                   'Test',
                   'Test',
                   'https://test.com'
                  ]
                ]
}
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"} -Uri $requestUri -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $body
```

If somebody know other way how `$body` could be defined to be acceptable by API - I would gladly see this!

@EDIT
Also I have found reason why it wasn't work in first approach. Thanks to more web searching I realized that values in JSON according to documentation is actually array of arrays (which is basically what I "hardcoded" in above example!).
"Correct way" of doing it looks like this:

```
$requestUri = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$($SpreadsheetID)/values/$("SheetName!A:F"):append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED"

$body = @{
    range = 'SheetName!A:F';
    values = @(
        ,@(
            'Test',
            'Test',
            'Test', 
            'Test', 
            'Test',
            'https://test.com'
        );
    );
};
$test = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $body

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"} -Uri $requestUri -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $test
```